# Displaying Tkinter Label with a variable

Tags: python, tkinter

Having trouble displaying a variable for the Tkinter Label
Code example

```
q=StringVar()
q="blah blah" 

test = Label(main, textvariable=q)
test.pack()
```

I try this code and nothing displays. I have also tried

```
q="blah blah"
test = Label(main, text= )+q 
test.pack()
```

but that still doesn't. I want label to display "blah blah" when I run.

Comment: insted of `q="blah blah" ` do `q.set("blah blah" )`

Comment: I've added an answer, do let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First your assigning `q` to be a `StringVar()` and then your asking it to be a string. To set the value of a tkinter variable, say `q.set('bla bla')` or you can also define it while defining variable itself, like `q = StringVar(value='bal bla')`.

To verify and understand better, say:

```
q = StringVar()
print(type(q))
q = 'bla bla'
print(type(q))
```

You will notice it will show a `tkinter.StringVar` first and then a `str` class for the second. So they both are not same.

Or as per your second example it should be something like:

```
q = 'bla bla'
test = Label(main, text=q)
```

What you were trying to do was concatenating a class and a string, which would give an error. Moreover you will get syntax error first, as your not passing anything to the `text` argument of `Label()`.